# RESTful API with CMS Made Simple

Tags: ajax, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I have a client with a content-heavy site built in CMS Made Simple. The redesign requires a mostly AJAX interface, and I think a frontend framework like Backbone or Angular would be the way to go.

I want to avoid moving off CMS Made Simple, though (client is used to that interface, it will be annoying to migrate all the data).

I think if I could find or create a RESTful api for CMS Made Simple, I'd solve my problem. But after searching around online, I only found CGSocialApp module, which seems to provide a limited API for things like user management. I've also looked into other AJAX solutions for CMS Made Simple, and there don't seem to be good modules for it.

If there is no ready-made solution for me, how complex would building a RESTful API module be? I haven't built a RESTFUL api in a PHP framework before.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

So, there is no easy answer for this question, as the CMSMS doesn't have a build-in RESTful API.

I would go for one of the two solutions:

**1. Output the content as hand made json.**

In CMSMS, you really have a lot of control on the templates. You could change the default templates to output json content instead of HTML content. The only issue is that the CMSMS will still send an http content-type header, that you can try to ignore in the JS part.

To access the menu, just remove it from the main template and create an empty page who output the `{menu}`with a custom template that also build json content.

That's the quick and dirty solution, but it should be very accessible in terms of doing it.

**2. Create a dedicated module.**

As far as I know, there are no modules that expose the CMSMS in RESTFul format, but a module is really very easy to build. Well, you can try to build it yourself, with the help of the community. It don't really solve the current problem, but it's a hint.

I hope it shed some light on the problem.